# delegate returned value to callback

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, winforms

I'm having a very tough time with the following problem although I think it souldnt be difficult to solve:
I have an application which calls a delegate when you click on a button. It looks like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyTaskWorkerDelegate worker = new MyTaskWorkerDelegate(returnANumber);
        AsyncCallback completedCallback = new AsyncCallback(DelegateMethod);

        object[] myArray = new object[1];
        myArray[0] = "The number is: ";

        worker.BeginInvoke(completedCallback,myArray);
    }
```

The method "returnANumber" is supposed to sleep one second an then return the number 100.
It looks like this:

```
    private int returnANumber()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return 100;
    }
```

When the sleep is over and the number was returned comes the tricky part. The array created in the click function gets passed to the callback method. This method is supposed to show a MessageBox showing the string of the array and the number returned from the delegate. The function looks like this:

```
    private void DelegateMethod(IAsyncResult arr)
    {
        object[] myArray = (object[])arr.AsyncState;

        //Messagebox should show "The number is: 100"
        MessageBox.Show(myArray[0].ToString() + theNumberFromTheMethos);
    }
```

I cant figure out how I can access the value which gets returned by the delegate method...
Please help me :(

Comment: You should replace all of that with `Task.Run()`, which is _far_ easier to use.

Comment: I edited your tags and removed [asp.net]. I assume it's a WinForms app, the way you're using `MessageBox.Show` and `button1_Click`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the return value via `MyTaskWorkerDelegate.EndInvoke`. Thus, you'd have to keep a reference to `MyTaskWorkerDelegate` and pass it into `DelegateMethod`. The way your code currently looks, you'd need a separate object to pass both `myArray` and `MyTaskWorkerDelegate` via `IAsyncResult.AsyncState`.

You can avoid that and greatly simplify your code, if you use an anonymous lambda/delegate and access the local variables. The C# compiler will do the magic of keeping the state:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyTaskWorkerDelegate worker = new MyTaskWorkerDelegate(returnANumber);

    object[] myArray = new object[1];
    myArray[0] = "The number is: ";

    AsyncCallback completedCallback = new AsyncCallback((ar) => 
    {
        var result = worker.EndInvoke(ar);

        // you cannot use MessageBox here, you're on a non-UI random pool thread
        Debug.Print(myArray[0].ToString() + result);
    });

    worker.BeginInvoke(completedCallback, null); // no need to pass the state
}
```

Another point, you cannot use `MessageBox` from your `AsyncCallback` delegate, you're on a random pool thread when the callback is called. You'd need to use [`Control.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that:

```
AsyncCallback completedCallback = new AsyncCallback((ar) => 
{
    var result = worker.EndInvoke(ar);

    // you cannot use MessageBox here, you're on a non-UI random pool thread
    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
    {
        // here you can use MessageBox, you're on the UI thread
        MessageBox.Show(myArray[0].ToString() + result);
    }));
});
```

Note, the purpose of `Control.BeginInvoke` is compeltely different from `Delegate.BeginInvoke`, despite the name similarity. It's used to invoke a callback asynchronously on WinForms UI thread.

That said, **you can simplify your code event more with [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and `async/await`**, as pointed out by @SLaks, if you can use .NET 4.5 (or .NET 4.0 + [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async) and VS2012+). Your code might be as simple as this:

```
private int returnANumber()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return 100;
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object[] myArray = new object[1];
    myArray[0] = "The number is: ";

    int result = await Task.Run(() => returnANumber());
    MessageBox.Show(myArray[0].ToString() + result);
}
```

Moreover, if the only reason for `Thread.Sleep(1000)` is a pause, you can use `Task.Delay` instead:

```
private async Task<int> returnANumber()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return 100;
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object[] myArray = new object[1];
    myArray[0] = "The number is: ";

    int result = await returnANumber();
    MessageBox.Show(myArray[0].ToString() + result);
}
```

This way, you won't be explicitly using a pool thread, at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it's just great! I'm using the TPL solution since the application is getting built in .NET 4.5 anyway. This is so much easier! Thanks again!

Comment: @colosso, no problem, glad it helped. If you go on with TPL/async/await, make sure to check the links from here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/async-await/info